# Trying to update Xubuntu 22.04 get error grub-efi-amd64-signed: Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.02+dfsg1-5) but 2.06-2ubuntu7 is to be installed

Tags: grub2

Hi I ran into the first problem in a while. Xubuntu 22.04 updated 11-3-22 and received error

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed: Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.02+dfsg1-5) but 2.06-2ubuntu7 is to be installed
```

Tried fixing broken packages with synaptic package manager but still get error.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't find the answer, another thread mentioned this fixed it (and it did for me as well)

```
sudo apt --only-upgrade install grub-efi-amd64-signed
```